# Convert elements of all lists in n-lists to floats?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a list of lists of lists, which looks like this:

`[['1', '1', '13', '23', '1.0', '9', '20051102', '20170330', '16', '9', '2', '2', '24', '46', '7232.17'], ['2', '1', '13', '23', '1.0', '9', '20051102', '20170331', '28', '4', '5', '4', '19', '51', '6171.145'], ['3', '1', '13', '23', '1.0', '9', '20051102', '20170327', '8', '3', '0', '2', '15', '14', '4666.224'], ['4', '1', '13', '23', '1.0', '9', '20051102', '20170329', '22', '2', '1', '4', '18', '42', '5479.682'], ['5', '1', '13', '23', '1.0', '9', '20051102', '20170328', '15', '5', '6', '9', '28', '37', '9411.681'], ['6', '1', '3', '27', '0.0', '9', '20051228', '20170303', '6', '1', '0', '0', '14', '21', '3757.115'], ['7', '1', '3', '27', '0.0', '9', '20051228', '20170301', '1', '0', '1', '3', '40', '45', '10521.261'], ['8', '1', '3', '27', '0.0', '9', '20051228', '20170320', '2', '0', '0', '0', '174', '171', '43113.562']`.

It is created by this code:
`lines = [[x for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]`

Now, all of the elements in all of the lists are strings, and if I try 
`lines = [[float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]` I get an error.

The thing is that if i try something like:

`if str in lines: 
     print(lines)`

which returns nothing.

I suspected that some empty strings might cause the problem, like: `['2976', '1', '1', '0', '', '4', '20160630', '20170318', '0', '0', '0', '0', '8', '2', '2125.364']` where the 4th element is empty..

What to do?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: what result do you whant if the string is empty?

Comment: @ddor254   File "TESTSET.py", line 8, in <module>
    lines = [[float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]
  File "TESTSET.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    lines = [[float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]
  File "TESTSET.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    lines = [[float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @BearBrown I only want the line to print if it contains an element of type string, but it does not print anything, which puzzles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write your own function to `float` that handle empty strings:

```
def myFloat(str):
    if str:
       return float(str)
    return <your_default_value> #e.g -1
```

and then:

```
lines = [[myFloat(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]
```

and you could always create new list without empty strings and then iterate over it.

***update:***

just use the `float(x)` only if not empty string , like so :

```
lines = [[float(x) for x in line.strip().split(',') if x] for line in myfile.readlines()[1:3000]]
```

please notice the `if x` at the end.

Comment: Problem is that it is firstly in the `lines` code, that it gets converted to a float